# Hyper-v VM DNS very slow only in IE. Firefox is fast

Tags: dns, virtual-machine, ip-address, hyper-v

I have a strange problem with a hyper-v vm my colleague copied me for test purposes.

When I start the vm (Windows 2008) and try to connect to it via Internet Explorer 10, then it takes very long till the Webpage is displayed. In Firefox it's very fast.

When I'm using the Ip-Address instead of the VM-Name then it' s also fast in IE.

Examples:

```
http://myserver/CRM2011
```

-->FF = FAST

-->IE = SLOW

```
http://192.168.178.20/CRM2011
```

-->FF = FAST

-->IE = FAST

Does anyone know what i can do here?
My Client pc has Windows 8.

thanks a lot.
Tobias